# Referenced object has value of nothing

Tags: vb.net

How to resolve 'referenced object has value of nothing' here.....
logDTO object having properties, of type string. 
Value of some of the property are empty. it throws the above quoted error. I tried with .ToString() but still throws error.

```
 Public Sub WriteJobLog(ByVal logDTO As JobLogDTO)
  Dim strArray As String() = {logDTO.Mode.ToString(), logDTO.UniqueId.ToString(), logDTO.ThreadId.ToString(), _
                         logDTO.StartTime.ToString(), logDTO.FinishTime.ToString(), logDTO.TimeTaken.ToString(), _
                         logDTO.PropertyId.ToString(), logDTO.ChannelId.ToString(), logDTO.URL.ToString(), _
                         logDTO.ExceptionOrResult.ToString(), logDTO.AvblWorkerThread.ToString(), logDTO.AvblPortThread.ToString(), _
                         logDTO.AcqrdWorkerThread.ToString(), logDTO.AcqurdPortThread.ToString(), logDTO.JobsToProcess.ToString()}
  Dim lLogObj As Logging = New Logging(JobType.JOB_TRANSACTTIONAL)
  lLogObj.WriteLogFile(String.Join(Configuration.LogDelimiter, strArray))
End Sub
```

**JobLogDTO**

```
   public class JobLogDTO
  {
    public string  Mode { get; set; }
    public string  UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string  ThreadId { get; set; }
    public string  StartTime { get; set; }
    public string  FinishTime { get; set; }
    public string  TimeTaken { get; set; }
    public string  PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string  ChannelId { get; set; }
    public string  URL { get; set; }
    public string  ExceptionOrResult { get; set; }
    public string  AvblWorkerThread { get; set; }
    public string  AvblPortThread { get; set; }
    public string  AcqrdWorkerThread { get; set; }
    public string  AcqurdPortThread { get; set; }
    public string  JobsToProcess { get; set; }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Value of logDTO object

```
         AcqrdWorkerThread  "24"    String
        AcqurdPortThread    "24"    String
        AvblPortThread      "400"   String
        AvblWorkerThread    "399"   String
        ChannelId           Nothing String
        ExceptionOrResult   Nothing String
        FinishTime          Nothing String
        JobsToProcess      "24" String
        Mode               "Parallel"   String
        PropertyId          Nothing String
        StartTime          "04.04.2013 12:17:25"    String
        ThreadId           "5"  String
        TimeTaken          Nothing  String
        UniqueId           "97693c1b-2bbc-4e40-a542-291568aeee4c"   String
        URL                Nothing  String
```

Comment: What's the value of logDTO and logDTO.Mode?

Comment: Did you check whether logDTO is nothing or not.? using a breakpoint

Comment: @Adrian Godong: Added value of logDTO. Please find the updated question.

Comment: @RajaPrabhu: Yes, some of the property values are nothing. I tried with .ToString() but still throws error.

Comment: If the object is nothing, .tostring will not work - because there is no object which could deliver its "tostring" value.
What you can do: Initialize your propertys with an empty value, in case of a string "".
Or modify your getter methods so that they are deliviering something else when the object is nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `.ToString()` function Converts the value of any `instance` to its equivalent `string` representation. But here your `instance` is nothing. That is why it is raising the exception `Referenced object has value of nothing`.

I would recommend that you can use `Trim()` in your case. It will simply return an `empty string` even if the passed `argument` is `nothing`.

**Ex:**

```
trim(logDTO.Mode)
```